# TableView NSFetchedResultsController CoreData: error

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview who is managed by an FetchResultController.
Let's say the fetch request give me 99 objects.
I would like to add an extra cell (an ad) at index 20.
Like my data is managed by an FetchResultController, I must play in numberOfRows to display or not my ad. But CoreData seems confused at the end of tableView.endUpdates().

`'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (100) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (99 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

I try to add a row between tableView.beginUpdate() and tableView.endUpdate()  in

`func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)`

but the tableView seems to only care about when NSFetchedResultController driving insert and deleting rows.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Core Data error, that's your table view telling you that it's confused. `UITableView` keeps careful track of the number of rows it's supposed to display. It asks how many rows there are a lot. It's critical that the number of rows returned from `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` change correctly when you insert or delete rows.

That means, if you call `insertRows(at:with:)` and insert some rows, the value returned by `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` **must** increase by the same number. What these messages are telling you is:

1. The table view asked how many rows to display, and you returned 0
2. You inserted 99 rows in your update
3. The table view asked how many rows to display again, and you returned 100

That's the problem. You started at 0, added 99, then claimed the result was 100. If you want to have the extra row, you need to insert one more row during the update. If you don't want to insert the row, you need to make sure that when the table view asks for the number of rows, you say 99 instead of 100.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for reply ! 

The problem is that I’m not inserting  rows during the update, the NSFetchedResults delegate fired didChange method and giving me NSFetchedResultsChangeType : .insert. I’ve followed Apple default implementation so I only have this line inside :   ```tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)```
I have checked numberOfRowsInSection and it always sending back good number of rows.

As my AD can be displayed or not, I will try to add this ad in footerView of one section and get section one with 20 mail and the second with the rest of rows

Comment: If you call `insertRows` during the update, then you are inserting rows during the update. Apple's default implementation doesn't include your ad cell, but your code needs to account for that one way or another. Your error message indicates that you are not returning the correct result from `numberOfRowsInSection`-- that's literally, exactly, what the error message means.